# LTO Backup problem in Ubuntu

Tags: backup, tar

I'm seeking advice how to troubleshoot this further...

I have a Adaptec ASC-1405 SAS card and a HP LTO-4 tape drive.

I make a normal tar backup, tar -cvf /dev/nst0 ...
This works with any fuzz.

But when trying to look at the tape with tar -tvf /dev/nst0 I get read error (I/O fault).
This seems to happen on random places. Two successive runs will not stop on the same file. When this happens, the tape stops, and tar freezes. Then after a while (several minutes) the error appears and the tape starts running again.

Any ideas?

I have successfully upgraded firmware and run all tests on the backup drive on the same hardware, just booting from a Windows 7 disk.

output from tar:
tar: /dev/nst0: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: /dev/nst0: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: /dev/nst0: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: /dev/nst0: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: A lone zero block at 33363361
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

---

mt -f /dev/nst0 status
SCSI 2 tape drive:
File number=0, block number=0, partition=0.
Tape block size 0 bytes. Density code 0x46 (LTO-4).
Soft error count since last status=0
General status bits on (41010000):
 BOT ONLINE IM_REP_EN

---

lspci
...
Serial Attached SCSI controller: Adaptec ASC-1405 Unified Serial HBA (rev 02)

---

uname -a
Linux host 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:44 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: Have you tried similar operations on windows? If all goes well, than this seems to be a driver issue. FYI: I have no problem with an *LSI SAS 9211-4i* host bus controller and a Tandberg LTO-3 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 (almost the same kerner as yours).